# glob function not work properly on m1 mac

Tags: python, image-processing, operating-system, glob

```
import cv2
import glob
from pathlib import Path
import os

path = "H:/TEZ/*.jpg"
path2 = "H:/TEZ/edit/"

for file in glob.glob(path):
    basename = os.path.basename(file)
    name = os.path.splitext(basename)
    img = cv2.imread(file)
    img_hsv=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    lower_red = np.array([0,95,50])
    upper_red = np.array([2,255,255])
    mask0 = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower_red, upper_red)

    lower_red = np.array([175,95,50])
    upper_red = np.array([180,255,255])
    mask1 = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower_red, upper_red)

    mask = mask0+mask1

    output_img = img.copy()
    output_img[np.where(mask==0)] = 0

    output_hsv = img_hsv.copy()
    output_hsv[np.where(mask==0)] = 0
    son = cv2.cvtColor(output_hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    cv2.imwrite("H:/TEZ/edit/" + name[0] + ".jpg", son)
```

this code work flawlessly on windows but when i try to convert these code in mac:

```
path = "/Users/turkerberkdonmez/Desktop/TEZ/*.jpg"
cv2.imwrite("/Users/turkerberkdonmez/Desktop/TEZ/edit2/" + name[0] + ".jpg", son)
```

nothing happens, what should i do?
i think glob function not work on mac like this?

Comment: Make sure that sandboxing isn't blocking access to the Desktop folder.

Comment: when i go into settings, all applications has the full disk access, but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar issue. Full Disk Access wasn't the permissions setting I needed but it was the Files and Folder permissions that needed to be checked.

I also noticed that you are trying to access the Desktop folder which is not located in the Documents folder. I would try putting your needed files in the Documents folder.

[image]